# Can you request `204 No Content`?

Tags: rest, http, http-headers

Is there a codified way to indicate to an HTTP server that the client would prefer not to receive content? A special `Accept` header or the like? Eg, `Accept: no-content`

When present, the server would return a `204 No Content` response. When not present, the server would default to the `application/json` representation.

The use case is for a particularly large `PUT` request. Getting the content back is useful for development and debugging, but costly for production systems. I realize this could be hacked together with custom headers or params; I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

*Edit: I am writing the service*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't control the server, you can't really. The best option you have is to kill the tcp connection as soon as you get the response.

If you are also developing the server though, you do have the option. The best design is to *not* send the result by default, and allow users to explicitly request the new presentation with this:

```
Prefer: return=representation
```

This header is defined in [rfc7240](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240).

Comment: Nice! Looks like IANA keeps a [registered list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-parameters/http-parameters.xml#preferences) of `Prefer` values. There is also `Prefer: return=minimal`. Small json ~= no json :+1:

Comment: Or, `204` is an encouraged return in [rfc7240 4.2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7240#page-9) for `Prefer: return=minimal`

Comment: Yes but I think that that's worse. There is no semantic meaning for the result of a PUT request (it could be anything), but the `return=representation` gives it explicit semantics. So imho it should be opt-in :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no general set of semantics for PUT that causes it to return the content. It's entirely up to the particular service. The HTTP specification says nothing about the content coming back at you. Either the particular service you are throwing PUTs at has some means of controlling its verbosity, or it does not. Since you have not specified it, no one can be more helpful than this.